# how to remove one tab out of two consequetive tabs in linux

Tags: linux, shell

i have a file in which all columns are tab separated. at some places two or more tabs are present consecutively. so i want to keep one tab out of two or more tabs. input file is as following-

```
10517-akr   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10518-akr       0   0   0   1   0   0   0
10515-akr   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0
10514-akr           0   1   17  0   0   0
10513-akr   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Desired out put is-

```
10517-akr   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
10518-akr   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
10515-akr   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0
10514-akr   0   1   17  0   0   0
10513-akr   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tr` to *squeeze* multiple repeated tabs into one:

```
tr -s '\t' < inputfile > outfile
```

Quoting `man tr`:

```
   -s, --squeeze-repeats
          replace each input sequence of  a  repeated  character  that  is
          listed in SET1 with a single occurrence of that character
```

Answer (score 1):

using `sed` to replace double-tab by single tab:

```
sed 's|\t\t|\t|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

or - if you want to replace any repetition of tabs:

```
sed 's|\t\t*|\t|g' inputfile > outputfile
```

note, that not all versions of sed understand `\t`. Just insert a literal tab instead (press <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> then <kbd>Tab</kbd>).